# iPhone: Do I need to implement all methods for UIScrollViewDelegate (or any delegate)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Suppose I make a UIViewController a UIScrollViewDelegate.

Do I need to implement all methods for the delegate, or can I just implement the 1 I care about?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you `cmd + click` in xcode where you have declared that you implement the protocol

```
<UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Xcode will take you to the header file where the protocol is defined. Here you can see that all of the methods for `UIScrollViewDelegate` are declared as `@optional` therefore you can just implement the ones you want.

If you prefer the documentation then `Apple` marks the required methods with `required method` in the `Tasks` section.

Additionally the compiler will show warnings if you say you conform to a protocol but do not implement required methods.